# Как свернуть форму по нажатию кнопки закрытия

Tags: c#

Как свернуть форму по нажатию кнопки закрытия (аналогично нажатию кнопки "свернуть", а не в трей)

Comment: А в куда свернуть?

Comment: В таскбар нужно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228966/how-to-minimize-a-window-to-the-taskbar-i-e-not-iconify

Comment: типо просто свернуть, как скайп на крестик сворачивается?

Comment: Да,да,да как скайп

Comment: Мне кажется автор путает таскбар и трей. Трей - это маленькие иконки рядом с часами. Таскбар - это внизу вся полоса, но обычно под этим понимают иконки работающих программ (чаще всего с названием если не отключено) правее кнопки "Пуск".

Comment: Нет,я к счастью ничего не путаю

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте обработчик события **Form.Closing** и напишете внутри следующий код:

```
e.Cancel = true;
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

[Form.Closing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: В трей сворачивается

Comment: Самое интереное то,что когда я убираю код на сворачивание в трей,все работает как надо

Comment: всмысле? если у тебя сворачивание в ещё и трей, то там скорее всего прописано скрытие формы, удали скрытие

Comment: По подробнее можно?

Comment: напиши код своей функции